# WCF - Sharing/caching of data between calls

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF & Service development and have a following question.

I want to write a service which relies on some data (from database for example) in order to process client requests and reply back. 
I do not want to look in database for every single call. My question is, is there any technique or way so that I can load such data either upfront or just once, so that it need not go to fetch this data for every request?

I read that having InstanceContextMode to Single can be a bad idea (not exactly sure why). Can somebody explain what is the best way to deal with such situation.

Thanks

Comment: It is still not clear. The service is going to be per call on Net TCP hosted as a Windows service. It is expected to receive a message, decorate/populate the message further and call another service to save data. 
I can see two calls to the other service, first to fetch some data on which calculation depends and then next call to save the data.

I was hoping to eliminate first call by loading that data only once. There must be something in WCF to support this kind of workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The BCL has a `Lazy` class that is made for this purpose. Unfortunately, in case of a transient exception (network issue, timeout, ...) it stores the exception forever. This means that your service is down forever if that happens. That's unacceptable. The `Lazy` class is therefore unusable. Microsoft has declared that they are unwilling to fix this.

The best way to deal with this is to write your own lazy or use something equivalent.

You also can use `LazyInitializer`. See the documentation.

I don't know how instance mode `Single` behaves in case of an exception. In any case it is architecturally unwise to put lazy resources into the service class. If you want to share those resources with multiple services that's a problem. It's also not the responsibility of the service class to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on amount of data to load and the pattern of data usage.

Assuming that your service calls are independent and may require different portions of data, then you may implement some caching (using `Lazy<T>` or similar techniques). But this solution has one important caveat: once data is loaded into the cache it will be there forever unless you define some expiration strategy (time-based or flush on write or something else). If you do not have cache entry expiration strategy your service will consume more and more memory over time.

This may not be too important problem, though, if amount of data you load from the database is small or majority of calls access same data again and again.

Another approach is to use WCF sessions (set `InstanceContextMode` to `PerSession`). This will ensure that you have service object created for lifetime of a session (which will be alive while particular WCF client is connected) - and all calls from that client will be dispatched to the same service object. It may or may not be appropriate from business domain point of view. And if this is appropriate, then you can load your data from the database on a first call and then subsequent calls within same session will be able to reuse the data. New session (another client or same client after reconnect) will have to load data again.